# Single UITest case on two simulators

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, uitest

I’m new in UITesting and I’m searching for any info about how to test this kind of case:
1. I have a single uitest
2. I need to start two simulators for each user
3. Then I want to do some interactions on those simulators (like log in on both, join a “room” on first and second and then check on first if second user is in “room” (it's a bit like uitesting messaging app))
Can I do this in XCode or I will need some external tools? Where can I search for more info? Maybe I should use different approach?

Comment: You can do it only if UI reflects on the app once second user enters the room. Basically UITesting is meant for checking the UI elements presence (element exists on the screen) or the text contains it.

Comment: Yeah, It will be visible on the screen, when second user will be present in the room, question is how to start second, separate simulator, that I could automate joining room by second user. I know that I can launch two instances of the app, but with different bundeId and switch between them, but not in my case, because I'm using socket connection, which is not working when app is not in foreground

Comment: You cannot automate this use case using UITesting. Perfecto is a tool where you can launch the app in multiple simulator but not sure how framework will consider with two simulators.

Comment: You should stub the network requests, simulating interaction with another user on a single simulator.